# flutter, if I open other apps, and return to my app after a few seconds it freezes

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem with my app, I use flutter
the app works fine, but when it is open and I decide to open other apps, and then I decide to go back to my app, my freeza app, my web page no longer scrolls inside the app.

so I have to close it and reopen it again, without viewing the other apps, what does it depend on?

in the main.dark use

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Permission.camera.request();
    await Permission.microphone.request();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: new MyApp()
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("FACECHAT | COMMUNITY")),
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      InAppWebView(
                        key: webViewKey,
                        initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.site.it/")),
                        initialOptions: options,
                        pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          webViewController = controller;
                        },
                        onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
                          return PermissionRequestResponse(
                              resources: resources,
                              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                        },
                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                          var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                          if (![ "http", "https", "file", "chrome",
                            "data", "javascript", "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                            if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                              // Launch the App
                              await launch(
                                url,
                              );
                              // and cancel the request
                              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                            }
                          }

                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        },
                        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                        },
                        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                          if (progress == 100) {
                            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            this.progress = progress / 100;
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                          print(consoleMessage);
                        },
                      ),
                      progress < 1.0
                          ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                          : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.goBack();
                      },
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.goForward();
                      },
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                      onPressed: () {
                        webViewController?.reload();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]))
    );
  }
}
```

I hope I have explained
simplifying, if I open my app, and then if I open other apps and then reopen my app, my app freezes and remains blocked